# Can I get the value of an input in a multiple file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello first of all sorry if Im not explaining very well but its difficult even to me. What Im try to do its get the value from an input to after that print that value into a label.

Here is what I have

[Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xLopjwh9/)

I show the preview of the image with a input down, I want to get the text that user types in that input.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <label for="files" class="hidden-print">Select multiple files:</label>
        <input id="files" class="hidden-print" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <output id="result" />
</div>
```

If have questions about something please let me know and again sorry if I not much clear.

Comment: Sorry to assume, but are you a Spanish speaker? In that case --> http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Na, just fails like everybody and problems to explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be relatively simple, just fetch and add an event listener after you have inserted the element into the (D.O.M.). In this case, you would add (right after `output.insertBefore(div, null)`):

```
// fetch the element
var input = document.getElementById('txt')
// attach an relevant event listener to it
input.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value) // what ever is typed
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLopjwh9/2/

I hope that helps!

Comment: This works fine, just one last question, how can I put the result into a label? I tried with $('#labe').val(pc) instead of console.log(pc).

Comment: Where is the label element?

Comment: Sorry, in that code there is no label, well imagine a label under the input or into a div under. Or just a bootbox.alert showing the result.

Comment: In that case,  $('#labe').val(pc) should work. Maybe it isn't because you spelled "labe" instead of "label", but that doesn't matter as long as the label element has an id that corresponds to whatever id you are fetching. Post another fiddle with the code that you're having trouble with and I'll help you.

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xLopjwh9/3/, the problem is that your code write the value of what Im typying but I want to get that value after user finish typing.

Comment: The thing is that, in this case, your label element is not an input so $('#label').val(pc) won't work, you would have had to do $('#label').text(pc). But regardless, you were calling that command in the wrong place, it needs to be inside the event callback you are listening to since that's where the data is coming from. The "pc" variable outside the outside the event callback would not contain the information you were expecting. See this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLopjwh9/4/

Comment: Bro! Thank you so much, that works perfect!! just there is a problem that only works with 1 file, but like I said in my question I need it with a multiple file upload, but I think that i can work with that.

Comment: Not a problem! If anything, post another question if you need assistance on making it work with multiple files, someone here will help you.